# Unable to specify foreign key in managed model to non-managed model (Django 3.2.7 / Postgresql 10.18)

Tags: python, django, django-models, postgresql-10

I am implementing a "profile model" in Django 3 that at its simplest is a two field model: a one-to-one relationship field to the default Django User model and a foreign key relationship to an unmanaged model TeamDim that is populated and managed by an ETL job outside the Django app. I'm using Postgresql 10 as the DB backend.

I had no trouble creating the initial table with the one-to-one field and placeholder teamname CharField, but adding the ForeignKey field causes the migration to fail with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "index" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

The primary key in TeamDim is `team_id` and is appropriately specified in the model definition, so I'm not sure where the reference to column `index` is coming from in the foreign key constraint the migrator is attempting to apply. Other *non-managed* models in my app have no trouble referencing TeamDim via foreign keys with the same declaration, so I'm not sure why it's failing in the managed case. Adding kwargs `db_index=False` or `to_field='team_id'` to the ForeignKey declaration don't remedy the issue.

Below are the two relevant models - TeamDim and CefhUser

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# our unmanaged dimension with primary key team_id
class TeamDim(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.team_id)}: {self.team_owner}/{self.team_shortname}'

    team_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    team_owner = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Owner')
    owner_formatted = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Owner')
    team_shortname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Team')
    team_fullname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Team')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'team_dim'

# and our managed profile model
class CefhUser(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # no problems here, migration is successful
    team_shortname = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True) 

    # but adding this field causes failure during migration
    team = models.ForeignKey('TeamDim', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

... and the migration script generated:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('cefh_hub_app', '0008_cefhuser'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='cefhuser',
            name='team',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, to='cefh_hub_app.teamdim'),
        ),
    ]
```

Edit: `\d+ team_dim` outputs:

```
                                      Table "public.team_dim"
     Column      |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 team_id         | bigint |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 team_owner      | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
 owner_formatted | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
 team_shortname  | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
 team_fullname   | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "team_dim_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "draft_fact" CONSTRAINT "draft_fact_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "keeper_fact" CONSTRAINT "keeper_fact_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "matchups_weekly_fact" CONSTRAINT "matchups_weekly_fact_opp_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (opp_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "matchups_weekly_fact" CONSTRAINT "matchups_weekly_fact_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "projections_weekly_fact" CONSTRAINT "projections_weekly_fact_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "season_dim" CONSTRAINT "season_dim_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "statlines_weekly_fact" CONSTRAINT "statlines_weekly_fact_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "transaction_fact" CONSTRAINT "transaction_fact_from_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (from_team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
    TABLE "transaction_fact" CONSTRAINT "transaction_fact_to_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (to_team_id) REFERENCES team_dim(team_id)
```

Comment: Does the `team_dim.team_id` column have an index? Can you show the output of `\d+ team_dim` from psql?

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for the reply, I added the \d+ output in the question. Confirmed it has an index.